# NSArray in NSDictionary stored in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, property-list

I'm just trying to save a dictionary of dictionary of array in NSUserdefaults without success. Here is my code:

```
+ (BOOL) userHasAlreadyLoad:(NSNumber *)territoryId year:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USER_SETTING_MONTHS_LOADED];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictOfTerritory = dict[[territoryId stringValue]];
    if (dictOfTerritory == nil)
        return NO;

    NSMutableArray *yearData = dictOfTerritory[[@(year) stringValue]];
    if (yearData == nil)
        return NO;

    if ([yearData containsObject:@(month)])
        return YES;
    return NO;
}

+ (void) setUserLoad:(NSNumber *)territoryId year:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USER_SETTING_MONTHS_LOADED] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictOfTerritory = [dict[[territoryId stringValue]] mutableCopy];
    if (dictOfTerritory == nil)
    {
        dictOfTerritory = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[[territoryId stringValue]] = dictOfTerritory;
    }
    NSMutableArray *yearData = [dictOfTerritory[[@(year) stringValue]] mutableCopy];
    if (yearData == nil)
    {
        yearData  = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    if (![yearData containsObject:@(month)])
    {
        [yearData addObject:@(month)];
    }
    dictOfTerritory[[@(year) stringValue]] = yearData;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:USER_SETTING_MONTHS_LOADED];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

When I run the app the first time, it saves the data properly which means the `yearData` will contain one month but after adding more data to that array I can't find them when calling userHasAlreadyLoad; I can just see one month for the same territoryId and Year which is the first month I added. Anything I missed here?

Comment: FYI - `NSUserDefaults` shouldn't be used to store app data. Write the dictionary to a plist file, as one other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get `dictOfTerritory`, you call `mutableCopy` on it, which gets you a copy of that dictionary. And you only save value to that copied dictionary, not the one that has reference in the main `dict` dictionary.

Try the following code where you're saving dictionaries.

```
    dictOfTerritory[[@(year) stringValue]] = yearData;
[dict setObject:dictOfTerritory forKey:[territoryId stringValue]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:USER_SETTING_MONTHS_LOADED];
```

Comment: I already figured it out but forget to update it. Thanks for your input.